# How to customize 'new' option in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When I'm using Eclipse to code in Java, I want to use the 'New' button (located below File, Edit...) to create a new class. I know it's possible because I've been able to use it like that on a different computer. However, the only options displayed are "Project", "Example", "Other...". So I have to select other and go find "Class".

I want a way to modify this list to include Java Project, Class, and whatever else I need. It's the same story when I right-click the src folder in the package explorer. I want to make a class in that folder, but I have to click other, navigate the new window to class, etc.

Can this be simplified?

Comment: I was on the debug perspective. That fixed it, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're in the right perspective. I see what you're looking for if I'm in the "Java" perspective, but not in other perspectives, such as "Java EE" or "Debug".

A "perspective" in Eclipse is the set of panes, toolbars, menus, etc. for a particular purpose. There should be toolbar buttons all the way on the right for them.

Answer (score 1):

In order to customize new option in Eclipse, On  the top of Eclipse, click on `Window`, `Navigate to > Perspective > Customize Perspective > Menu Visibility > file > new.`
Now you can customize new option.